# C++ Nested Template Classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

How can I return a "B" type using a method of an "A" class? For example:

```
template <typename T> class A{

    //something

        template <typename V> class B{

        //something

        };

    B& foo(){
        B<T> y; //the variable must have the same type T of the father class (for my exercise)
        //something
        return y;
    }
};
```

main:

```
A <int> o;
o.foo();
```

Once I try to compile it, it gives me these errors:

"invalid use of template-name 'A< T >::B' without an argument list" at "B& foo()..."

and

"'class A' has no member named 'foo'"

I have written the function "foo" after closing the class B, so it might be right...

Comment: Just a hint. Here: `B& foo(){`. The error is quite easy to understand.

Comment: You cannot omit template arguments when returning `B`, that would only be allowed if you were willing to return `A<T>` (i.e. `A` with the same template parameters as `foo` is declared within). You should return `B<T>`, not simply `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. The `public` access specifier is missing. `foo()` won't be accessible outside `class A` otherwise.
2. You need to add the template arguments to the return type as well, i.e. declare the member function as `B<T> foo()`. Even better, let the compiler deduce the return type (works with C++14 and beyond), so just write `auto foo()`
3. You are returning a reference to a local variable, which leads to undefined behavior. Just return the local variable as value, due to [*copy elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) you won't need to worry about performance issues.

With that in mind, your code should work.